# How to Define Relative Path?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, path

I have heard about relative paths and I think that they are of good use.
But, I do not know how how to define a relative path.
For instance, I have a Power Point presentation in which I use an audio (or video) during the slide show. I place these files (the presentation itself and the audio(/video)) in a folder. I would like to copy this folder to a removable drive so that I can use it in any system, but to achieve this, I should give the file name of the audio(/video) as relative path.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: would it help to create shortcut for these files. They can be relative ? http://www.csparks.com/Relative/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your presentation first and then save linked files to the same place you placed your presentation(same folder on the same disk). Your links will continue to work when you move presentation with the linked files.
You should put your files in the same folder as the saved presentation BEFORE linking to them.

Comment: Will that work? For instance, I have a removable drive connected to this PC( which I am working now), it has the drive letter K, I place the presentation along the necessary files in a folder( say "school")  which is in the K drive. Then, I remove the removable disk and connect it to another PC, there it's drive letter is E. If I haven't given the links as relative links, it will not work(I think so).

Comment: It will work. @RogUE

Comment: As I know. MS Office try store file name as relative, if it lie in folder of presentation or subfolder of it.

Comment: To add to Davidenko's answer:  You should put your files in the same folder as the saved presentation BEFORE linking to them.

Comment: This does NOT work in Office 2016.

Comment: For a detailed investigation of the current behavior of PowerPoint 365 on Windows 10 in this area, see [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1628319/1273143) to a related question, "[Linking OneDrive media in PowerPoint presentation when OneDrive is on different paths](https://superuser.com/q/1550979/1273143)".

Answer (score 1):

For me I did this:

1. Open File
2. Export or Save&send or share
3. Package presentation for CD, if you have inserted videos or audio files to your PP move to step 5, they will be part of the presentation (as embedded files) automatically.
4. Keep your linked files here if they are setups, files.exe etc,
5. Copy to folder, that is.

Now you can keep it on USB flash and use it wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me with office 2016.

Here's a workaround that did work for me:
save the presentation with the added absolute hyperlink as .xml
open with your editor of choice
search the name of the file that you're linking
in the target tag remove everything but file name and extension (assuming it's in the same folder) e.g.:

> Target="myVideo.mp4"

save and open again in pp

Answer (score -1):

Place all files to be used in a folder
Create your powerpoint with one slide and save it to this folder - **Critical step**
Add slides and links and save. Links should come up with just the filename, not the total path to the file.

Once this is done you should be able to move the whole folder without any problems.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people post. Part of providing a good answer is by making sure someone else didn't already post the same solution. Another answer containing the same solution to the stated problem was already posted by davidenko, [here](http://superuser.com/a/855665/482177), in a similar or higher quality than your answer.